# Webform Localization does not work

Tags: 7, webforms, i18n-l10n

I have downloaded the [Webform Localization](http://drupal.org/project/webform_localization) module from Drupal.org, but it is not working to translate form, and I want to keep a single webform across all nodes.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Which version did you install? Did you follow what reported in the project page?

Comment: yes i do , i use drupal 7 version but it dos not work translations

Answer (score 0):

If you create webform first and then install webform localization module , the module will see only new components in webform , so try to open each component and save it then go to Regional and language > translate interface > strings , check "webform localization" and "fields" then "Refresh strings" , then back to translate interface > translate , search for your components labels and translate them